# session_start() вызывает ошибку Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Cессия начинается на странице index.php, при этом session_start() возвращает true, и в $_SESSION записываются значения. Затем по кнопке происходит переход на другую страницу forms.php, которая начинается с такого кода:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

session_start() возвращает true, но значения массива записанного в $_SESSION, обновляются, имеют значение null, хотя в предыдущей странице значения у массива были. Ключи массива остались.

все без пробелов, кодировка UTF-8 без BOM. Проект развернут на на Open Server используется xdebug и PHPStorm.

В результате после отработки скриптом стр. 2, выдает следующие сообщения об ошибках:

```
PHP Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
PHP Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
PHP Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
PHP Warning: main(): Property access is not allowed yet in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
PHP Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
PHP Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
PHP Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
PHP Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /W:/domains/wms.local/forms.php on line 4
```

Подскажите,  в чем причина ошибок? Почему обнуляются значения массива, сохраненного в сессии и как этого избежать?
Обгуглил все в англоязычном интернете, ничего пока не нашел.

Заранее спасибо всем за любый идеи.

Answer (score 0):

Из этого путанного вопроса (казалось бы - где сессии, а где mysqli) не очень понятно, в чем конкретно состоит проблема, но если предположить, что сообщение об ошибке действительно связано со стартом сессии, то проблема очевидна - соединение с БД невозможно сохранить в сессии. При каждом запросе к РНР надо соединяться с БД заново. Нет, бояться этого не нужно, так работают все сайты на РНР. "Улучшать" или "оптимизировать" это не нужно. Надо просто один раз соединиться с БД за все время работы скрипта.

Если же объект mysqli не сохраняется в сессии, и ошибка вызвана другими причинами, то надо искать код, который закрывает соединение с БД. Поскольку именно это является причиной ошибки Couldn't fetch mysqli

Comment: если из кода убрать session_start() ошибка пропадает. При отладке она появляется сразу после прохождения кодом session_start() .  Я действительно пытаюсь сохранить в сессии соединение с БД, оно сохраняется, это видно в $_SESSION, но при переходе на другую страницу данные пропадают. Если для этих данных имеется исключение, и они не могут храниться  в сессии, тогда понятно.

Comment: Так и есть ошибка была потому, что я сохранял подключение к БД в $_SESSION, видимо, этого делать нельзя. Проверил путем сохранения других данных, все работает без ошибок.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотри настройки сервера `session_save_path`.

Вообще может, что у тебя сервер считает, что с **www** и без - два разных сайта.

Встречал такие проблемы. Прикол был не в обновлении, а в том, что 2 сессии были. Посмотри также настройки `.htaccess`.

Comment: mepihindeveloper, спасибо! 1) session_save_path все ОК, файл сессии лежит на месте, 2) файла.htaccess нет вообще (пока проект в стадии разработки) 3)соответственно www неоткуда появиться. А как вычислить возможность наличия 2-х сессий?

Comment: На форумах прочитал, что 2 сессии может быть из-за www. Тебе надо проверить куда отправляется запрос. Потому что вызов запуска сессии не обновляет ничего...

Comment: @Sturmer посмотри вот этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242347/4772782. Проблемы могут быть также с правами на запись сессии `is_writable(session_save_path())` на сервере и другими. Мне кажется, что ты что-то упускаешь.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/334045)

Comment: @ mepihindeveloper Вот я и спрашиваю: "Что я упускаю?". Прошелся по чеклисту по ссылке в твоем комментарию, еще раз проверил доменные имена, файл сессии, который формируется именно при переходе на другую страницу, при этом он содержит ключи массива, а значения нулевые!  Почему файл сессии искажен? Куки файлы нормально формируются удаляются (PHPSESID и XDEBUG).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не согласен с вами. В моем сообщение есть ответ, который призывает проверить настройки сервера в определенной секции. Мало того, что я предложил ответ в области запросов с www и без него. Не вижу здесь "не ответа на вопрос"